# c# Converter getting Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to simply do some Math on my custom control. I need to take a "Width" value and divide it by the Converter Paramater.

Here is the Binding:

```
<Border x:Name="circleBorder"
     Grid.Row="0"
     CornerRadius="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=circleGrid}"
     Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=circleGrid}"
     Height="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=circleGrid}"
     BorderBrush="White"
     BorderThickness="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CalculateBorder}, Path=Width, ElementName=circleBorder, ConverterParameter=30}">
```

And this is the converter, which should do some simple Math.

```
public class CalculateBorder : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {   
        return ((double)value / (double)parameter);
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error on `return ((double)value / (double)parameter);`:

> Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: It sounds as if your `parameter` or `value` may not actually be a double. Try using `Convert.ToDouble()` instead of a direct cast, as it will handle more cases correctly.

Comment: Show us what CalculateBorder is. That is the pivotal missing information here. Best way to prove this: don't use the parameter in your `Convert` method, just divide `(double)value` by 2.2.

Comment: You should debug this stuff before asking.  What's in `value` and `parameter` when you're doing the conversion?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your converter to see if the value is not nan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that it is not possible to unbox `parameter` because in this case `parameter` is a `string`.

The solution is converting the parameter to double with the [`Convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx) class

```
var yourDouble = Convert.ToDouble(parameter);
```

The problem of the above code is that `Convert` is defined as your `Convert` method of the `IValueConverter`. So you need to specify the full namespace by adding `System`. The complete expression looks like this:

```
var yourDouble = System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter);
```

to make clear to the compiler that you want to use the `System.Convert` class

---

Moreover the property `BorderThickness` has the type `Thickness`. so you should return a `Thickness` object reference instead of a `double`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to return System.Windows.Thickness like below,

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
 {           
    return new Thickness(10,10,10,10);
 }
```

The BorderThickness accepts System.Windows.Thickness

The  converter parameter `value` gives the `object` of `Thickness` class so you need to convert it to match your logic.

**MSDN**

```
public System.Windows.Thickness BorderThickness { get; set; }
```

Member of System.Windows.Controls.Border

Summary:
Gets or sets the relative System.Windows.Thickness of a System.Windows.Controls.Border.

Returns:
The System.Windows.Thickness that describes the width of the boundaries of the System.Windows.Controls.Border. This property has no default value.

Comment: See above first post.

Comment: have you tried to return Thickness ? binding seams to be correct.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and it's the same error

Comment: `return new Thickness((double)value / (double)parameter);`

Comment: Your solution points to another problem of the implementation, but the original error is a cast error caused in the cast `(double)parameter`as mentioned in my answer

Comment: the `value` cant be converted to double.

Answer (score 2):

object parameter is an **string**

```c#
return ((double)value / Convert.ToDouble(parameter));
```